# Persistent datum conflict error. Datums are the same

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, coordinate-system, error, datum

I'm clipping a number of features using other feature layers, and was careful to get everything into WGS84 beforehand, using what I thought were the proper datum transformations.  Now I keep getting Error 001003, Datum conflict between input and output.  I'm not sure if this is referring to my input shapefiles, or if it's a problem with output coordinate environment settings, or none of the above.

[image: Feature 1 Coordinate System Info]

[image: Feature 2 Coordinate System Info]

Contents of the .prj file of the input feature:

> GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],VERTCS["Unknown
>   VCS",VDATUM["Unknown"],PARAMETER["Vertical_Shift",0.0],PARAMETER["Direction",1.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Contents of the .prj file of the clip feature:

> GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

Any ideas?

Comment: So what's the gp environment output coordinate system set to? "same as input"? Also, if you're running gp through ArcMap, what's the coordinate system of the data frame? If it's different, that can also trigger this warning.

Comment: The data frame has the same coordinate system info, and yes, the environment output coordinates setting is "same as input."

Comment: Possibly one thing to try--open a new map document. Add each dataset one-by-one using Add Data. Does the datum transformation warning get triggered? If so, there is something different in the data's coordinate systems. Since these are shapefiles, could you post the contents of their prj files?

Comment: I've tried this, and the usual warning is not triggered when adding the second shapefile to the data frame.  I've posted the .prj file contents... they're not identical, but it looks like the important stuff is right.  I haven't really looked at these before though.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe the VCS is causing the warning message. Now that we've check them--I would ignore the warning. It is a warning, not an error.

Comment: If you're confident that they are WGS84/DD then you could (zip up a backup and) define them all to be the same, overwriting existing coordinate systems. The only difference seems to be the vertical datum (unknown) and by reasserting will avoid concerning warnings. I encounter mismatched coordinate system definitions frequently when taking data between product platforms and reasserting the known coordinate system with an ESRI generated coordinate system helps ESRI work with the files.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I think you should write your Comment up as an Answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're confident that they are WGS84/DD, based on the information you have provided that appears to be the case, then you could (zip up a backup and) define them all to be the same, overwriting existing coordinate systems.

The only difference seems to be the vertical datum (unknown) and by reasserting will avoid concerning warnings.

I encounter mismatched coordinate system definitions frequently when taking data between product platforms and reasserting the known coordinate system with an ESRI generated coordinate system helps ESRI work with the files.